# Get the descriptor histogram from images using BOW in openCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, histogram, k-means

I have the cluster centers (vectors) which I calculated using Kmeans. And I can calculate the feature vectors of an image and store it in a matrix. My problem is, how to get the histogram of occurrences of visual words of a particular image using the data I have. Im using OPENCV.
Can someone help please?

Comment: I think this link will answer your question:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O

Comment: Actually thats not what I want. I have seen that example and the problem is these two lines.

 'Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor(new SiftDescriptorExtractor);    
 
    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor,matcher);'

I don't need a extractor. I already have my feature vectors. How to use my set of feature vectors to get the image descriptor (histogram)